# Error connecting to Firestore - NoSuchFieldError EPOLL_DOMAIN_CLIENT_CHANNEL_TYPE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a google app engine java application using the admin SDK firestore scheme.
My IDE is Intellij Idea Ultimate Edition 2022.1.4.

My app worked well until I tried to add support for google storage service (enabling new apis), then the connection to firestore with FirestoreClient.getFirestore() began to throw a new error.

**This is the output console:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: EPOLL_DOMAIN_CLIENT_CHANNEL_TYPE
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.UdsNettyChannelProvider.isAvailable(UdsNettyChannelProvider.java:34)
at io.grpc.ManagedChannelRegistry$ManagedChannelPriorityAccessor.isAvailable(ManagedChannelRegistry.java:172)
at io.grpc.ManagedChannelRegistry$ManagedChannelPriorityAccessor.isAvailable(ManagedChannelRegistry.java:168)
at io.grpc.ServiceProviders.loadAll(ServiceProviders.java:68)
at io.grpc.ManagedChannelRegistry.getDefaultRegistry(ManagedChannelRegistry.java:96)
at io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider.provider(ManagedChannelProvider.java:41)
at io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(ManagedChannelBuilder.java:39)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:350)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.<init>(ChannelPool.java:105)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.create(ChannelPool.java:83)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:236)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:230)
at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:201)
at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:132)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.spi.v1.GrpcFirestoreRpc.<init>(GrpcFirestoreRpc.java:125)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreRpcFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:88)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreRpcFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:80)
at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getRpc(ServiceOptions.java:564)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions.getFirestoreRpc(FirestoreOptions.java:358)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreImpl.<init>(FirestoreImpl.java:79)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:71)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:64)
at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getService(ServiceOptions.java:544)
at com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient.<init>(FirestoreClient.java:51)
at com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient.<init>(FirestoreClient.java:29)
at com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient$FirestoreClientService.<init>(FirestoreClient.java:95)
at com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient.getInstance(FirestoreClient.java:85)
at com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient.getFirestore(FirestoreClient.java:78)
at com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient.getFirestore(FirestoreClient.java:64)
at com.lorensys.manager.Herramienta.<init>(Herramienta.java:64)
at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:120)
```

**This is the maven depency tree:**

```
[INFO] ------------------------< com.lorensys:manager >------------------------
[INFO] Building manager 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ manager ---
[INFO] com.lorensys:manager:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:jar:9.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.41.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.api:api-common:jar:2.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:jar:1.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:31.1-jre:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:jar:2.0.10:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-datastore:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core-http:jar:2.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.auth:google-auth-library-credentials:jar:1.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-apache-v2:jar:1.41.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-appengine:jar:1.41.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.api:gax-httpjson:jar:0.98.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.opencensus:opencensus-contrib-http-util:jar:0.31.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-cloud-datastore-v1:jar:0.94.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.cloud.datastore:datastore-v1-proto-client:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-protobuf:jar:1.41.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-api:jar:1.45.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-context:jar:1.45.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.threeten:threetenbp:jar:1.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.19.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.api:gax:jar:2.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:3.21.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core:jar:2.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:jar:3.19.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-iam-v1:jar:1.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:jar:1.41.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:jar:1.41.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.13.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:jar:1.33.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.opencensus:opencensus-api:jar:0.31.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:jar:v1-rev20220210-1.32.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-firestore:jar:3.0.21:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core-grpc:jar:2.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:1.45.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.android:annotations:jar:4.1.1.4:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.21:runtime
[INFO] |  +- io.perfmark:perfmark-api:jar:0.23.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-cloud-firestore-v1:jar:3.0.21:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.cloud:proto-google-cloud-firestore-bundle-v1:jar:3.0.21:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.opencensus:opencensus-contrib-grpc-util:jar:0.31.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:jar:1.45.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:jar:1.45.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.api:gax-grpc:jar:2.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-alts:jar:1.45.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-grpclb:jar:1.45.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.conscrypt:conscrypt-openjdk-uber:jar:2.5.1:runtime
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-auth:jar:1.45.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:jar:1.45.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-xds:jar:1.45.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-services:jar:1.45.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- com.google.re2j:re2j:jar:1.5:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.67:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.67:runtime
[INFO] |  +- io.opencensus:opencensus-proto:jar:0.2.0:runtime
[INFO] |  \- io.grpc:grpc-stub:jar:1.45.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:jar:v1-rev20211108-1.32.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api:jar:2.3.0:provided
[INFO] +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-iamcredentials:jar:2.0.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-cloud-iamcredentials-v1:jar:2.0.13:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-filestore:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-cloud-filestore-v1:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-cloud-filestore-v1beta1:jar:0.4.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage-transfer:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-cloud-storage-transfer-v1:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] \- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-nio:jar:0.123.27:compile
[INFO]    \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
```

I bet this is a conflict between libraries but I don't know how to fix it.
A Roll back to previous version of pom.xml file didn't work.

Any hint?